# Split method returning blank array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm having a problem with the split function returning a blank array. When any index is called from the array, it throws an index out of bounds exception. Here is the code:

```
class splitNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "3.84";
        String[] sep = number.split(".");
        System.out.println(sep[0]);
    }
}
```

Is there any fix or workaround for this? I'm using Java SE 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"." is a special character in regex and String's [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method accepts regex, which you need to escape like:

```
String[] sep = number.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted elsewhere, `String#split` takes a regex.  One alternate way to construct that regex is to use [`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-):

```
String number = "3.84";
String[] sep = number.split(Pattern.quote("."));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sep));
```

This saves you from typing a bunch of tedious escape chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use "\."

"Note that this takes a regular expression, so remember to escape special characters if necessary, e.g. if you want to split on period . which means "any character" in regex, use either split("\.") or split(Pattern.quote("."))."

[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)